# How can i texture the whole thing on surfaces that are created with an active boolean modifier?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, boolean-modifier

The object isn't textured on surfaces that are the result of a boolean modifier. I tried generated, uv and object input for the mapping but they all have the same results. Different uv unwrapping methods don't change anything either. I don't want to apply the boolean modifiers because they are animated. For example the holes open up by scaling the boolean cylinder from x&y 0 to 1. I made the same animation without boolean modifiers, instead with shape keys but it distorts the texture and doesn't work out properly, so i want to keep the boolean modifers unapplied[image: grey areas = cut by boolean]

Comment: Have you tried adding your texture to the modifier itself as well as your main object?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it perfectly!

Comment: Good! I don't know **why** it works, but it does for me! :^)